# Django: How to get total cart item in ecommerce

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I am trying to add the total item in the cart, but I keep getting

> <property object at 0x000001CFFDED8228>:

could anybody help?

View.py

```
class checkout(ListView):
model = OrderItem    
template_name = 'product/checkout.html'

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(checkout, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['orderQty'] = Order.get_cart_items
    return context
```

model.py

```
class Order(models.Model):
customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
date_ordered = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
complete = models.BooleanField(default=False, null = True, blank=False)
transaction_id = models.CharField(max_length= 200, null=True)


def __str__(self):
    return str(self.id)
  

@property
def get_cart_items(self):
    orderitems = self.orderitem_set.all()
    total = sum(item.quantity for item in orderitems)
    return total  
    

size_choices = (('small', 'S'),
            ('medium', 'M'),
            ('large', 'L'))
class OrderItem(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=0, blank=True, null=True)
    size = models.CharField(max_length= 200,choices= size_choices, default=0)


    @property
    def get_total(self):
        total = self.product.price *self.quantity
        return total
```

template.html:

```
<div class="row-1">
        <div style="flex:2;"><strong>Total Items</strong>:<span style="float: right;">{{orderQty}}</span></div>
        <hr>
        <div style="flex:2;"><strong>SubTotal</strong>:<span style="float: right;">$387</span></div>
        <hr>
        <div style="flex:2; margin-top:10px"><strong>Shipping</strong><span style="float: right;">$54</span></div>
        <hr>
    </div>    
    <div>
        <div style="flex:2; text-align:center"><h6>Total: $387</h6></div>
        <input id="form-button" class="btn btn-success btn-block" type="submit" value="Pay">
    </div
```

I believe these files contain the problem but from researching online I can't seem to pinpoint exactly what it is. The function based view of my website was working fine until I moved to class-based view my views.py file. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is with this line of code:

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(checkout, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['orderQty'] = Order.get_cart_items # <----
    return context
```

You are just creating function object instead of calling it. Changing that line to this should solve the problem:

```
context['orderQty'] = Order.get_cart_items()
```

**EDIT** When you define `@property`, your function becomes no longer function object but property object. Since `property` is `descriptor` and is not callable, it will throw that error. For more information, check this [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/descriptor.html#properties). So, I would suggest you to remove `@property` at function definition to resolve this issue.

Comment: Thanks. Now i am getting the 'property' object is not callable error